# Why Prefix data-* don't work in Angular 9?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a problem with a simple component in angular 9.
The code :

Component :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `<h1>Hello {{name}}!</h1>`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class HelloComponent  {
  @Input() name: string;
}
```

Html :

```
<hello data-name="Dark Vador Angular 9"></hello>
```

The code is the same in angular 7 and angular 9, but on angular 9, it don't work.
If i remove prefix data-, it's work. But why, it's a break change in angular 9, i didn't see anythings in documentation.

Any idea ?

Two stackblitz for test :
Angular 7 : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7-master
Angular 9 : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zan6uc

Comment: I don't see anything in [the v7 documentation](https://v7.angular.io/guide/template-syntax#input-and-output-properties) about using `data-` to bind to an `@Input()`-decorated property. I don't know that it's a breaking change if it's not documented...

Comment: I think the behavior you are describing in the Angular7 version is undocumented. It feels like it's a bug that data-* attributes, are working the way they do - the data-* prefix should NOT be stripped, and hence it should NOT be bound to to your input.

Comment: I ask a question in github of angular : https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/37592

Answer (score 1):

You actually have to use a [Attribute Binding Syntax](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax) instead:

```
<hello [attr.data-name]="'Dark Vador Angular 9'"></hello>
```

or

```
<hello [attr.data-name]="someProperty"></hello>
```

Comment: it's not work : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zan6uc with  <hello [attr.data-name]="'Dark Vador Angular 9'"></hello>

Comment: It is working. Look at the DOM in your stackblitz. the `data-name` attribute works just fine.

Comment: I do not understand your comment.

Comment: sorry, i just want to say : i add a new answer to my question : https://stackoverflow.com/a/62393542/6389566

Comment: You can see that `data-name` attribute in your "answer". Please mark this as the answer.

Comment: Yes, i agree with you, i see data-name in dom. But data-name is not recognise by angular. And the comportement is not the same between angular 7 and angular 9. I open a github issue here : https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/37592